# Oracle Listagg equivalent in lambda c#

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, lambda

Is there any lambda expression in c# equivalent in oracle Listagg?

I have a query here from oracle

```
FullName      Amount
  Rey            20
  Roy            20
  Rylie          21
  Rylolo         21
  Rembu          40

 select LISTAGG (FullName, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FullName) names,  Amount 
 from TableSample
 group by Amount
```

and this query will display like this

```
FullName      Amount
 Rey,Roy        20
 Rylie,Rylolo   21
 Rembu          40
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your C# code, but `string.Join` is the closest C# equivalent to `LISTAGG`.  It seems like you should group the data by `Amount` and include

```
string.Join(",", g => g.Select(i=>i.FullName))
```

in your final `Select` projection.